# MVVM binding textbox, button and listview

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to bind a textbox (named Labour) and textblock (which shows time) with listview. Listview should show a names of labours and times that they're takes after cliking button "Add item". I've already tried to use observablecollection but I'm doing something wrong. Data in ListView should be separated in two columns.
How can i do that ?

XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="LabourTimer.View.LabourMainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LabourTimer.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:LabourTimer.ViewModel"        
        Title="Labour timer" Height="600" Width="515">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewmodel:LabourViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Timer:" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTime}" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Label Content="Labour name:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Labour" Text="{Binding labourName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Content="Start/Stop" Command="{Binding StartStopCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Reset" Command="{Binding ResetCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Add to list" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Remove from list"/>

        </StackPanel>
        <ListView  x:Name="listView" Height="Auto" Margin="0,5" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MinWidth="300">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Labour name" Width="400" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Time in seconds" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace LabourTimer.ViewModel
{

    public class LabourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DispatcherTimer _timer;
        private string _currentTime;
        private int _seconds;
        private bool _running;


        public ICommand StartStopCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ResetCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddCommand { get; set; }
        public string CurrentTime
        {
            get { return _currentTime; }
            set { _currentTime = value;
                OnPropetyChanged("CurrentTime");
            }
        }


        public LabourViewModel()
        {
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
            _running = false;
            CurrentTime = "0";

            LoadCommands();

        }

        private void LoadCommands()
        {
           StartStopCommand = new CustomCommand(StartStopTimer, CanStartStopTimer);
           ResetCommand = new CustomCommand(ResetTimer, CanResetTimer);
           AddCommand = new CustomCommand(AddLabour, CanAddLabour);
        }

        private void AddLabour(object obj)
        {


        }

        private bool CanAddLabour(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private bool CanResetTimer(object obj)
        {
            if (CurrentTime != "0")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        private void ResetTimer(object obj)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            CurrentTime = "0";
            _seconds = 0;
        }

        private void StartStopTimer(object obj)
        {
            if (_running == false)
            {
                _timer.Start();
                _running = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _timer.Stop();
                _running = false;
            }
        }

        private bool CanStartStopTimer(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }

        private void TimerTick(object send, EventArgs e)
        {
            _seconds++;
            CurrentTime = _seconds.ToString();
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropetyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

CustomCommand:

```
 public class CustomCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Predicate<object> canExecute;

        public CustomCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }


        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            bool b = canExecute == null ? true : canExecute(parameter);
            return b;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow:

```
public partial class LabourMainWindow : Window
{
    public LabourMainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new LabourViewModel();

    }
```

Comment: I've deleted "DataContext = new LabourViewModel()" from LabourMainWidnow and added datacontext to XAML.

Comment: Your code example has too much code in it. Please read [mcve], to understand what is meant by both  **complete** and **minimal**. Read also [ask], and especially the articles linked at the bottom of that page, to understand why it's so important to meet both criteria. As for your specific issue, it's not even clear what you're asking. Are you having trouble getting the data displayed in the `ListView`? With reacting to changes in selection? With displaying data in the other `TextBlock` and `TextBox` elements? Please narrow the question, so it's more clear and specific.